# label the values in a data frame by using the values in another data frame as condition

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

1. I want to take 2 data frames, namely a and b.
2. Check a specific condition in the second column of a.
3. For the rows that are meeting that specific condition in a$col2, take a value in a different column of a; a$col3, and
4. Check if that value meeting another condition in the data frame b. The condition is that the value of a should be in an interval ; b$col4 <= x <= b$col5 and print another column of b in the same row with that matching interval.
5. Print another column of b, b$col6, corresponds to the matching interval row, b$col6

And finally it should iterate for each number from 1 to 10 as the first condition described in 2nd step.

In other words, I want to label the values in a, according to the interval they belong to in b.

```
for i in (1: 10){
  if (a$col2 == i){
    for (x in a$col3){
    b$col6[x >= b$col4 & x <= b$col5]

}
}
}
```

Here I am getting “error message "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" and “Error: unexpected condition, "}" in ‘}’”.
I also tried different versions of the code but in my opinion this is the closest one to the solution.

I am demonstrating the desired output below:

```
a:

col1 col2 col3
.   1   10
.   1   15
.   2   2
.   9   5


b:

col1    col2     col3   col4    col5    col6
.       .       .       1       3       label1
.       .       .       4       6       label2
.       .       .       9       11      label3
.       .       .       12      20      label4
.       .       .       70      80      label5
.       .       .       75      77      label6


output:

label3
label4
label1
label2
```

I appreciate your help. Thank you.